# Tensorflow: Convert Tensor to numpy array WITHOUT .eval() or sess.run()

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

How can you convert a tensor into a Numpy ndarray,  without using eval or sess.run()?

I need to pass a tensor into a feed dictionary and I already have a session running.

Comment: Think of a Tensor as a placeholder in the computation graph, it has no value, therefore you can't just convert it to a Numpy array. You can, however, "query" the value that flows to it in the computation using eval or run. What exactly are you trying to achieve? There may be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that you say "already have a session running" implies a misunderstanding of what sess.run() actually does.

If you have a tf.Session() initiated, you should be able to use it to retrieve any tensor using sess.run(). If you need to retrieve a variable or constant tensor this is very straight forward.

```
value = sess.run(tensor_to_retrieve)
```

If the tensor is the result of operations on placeholder tensors, you will need to pass them in with feed_dict.

```
value = sess.run(tensor, feed_dict={input_placeholder: input_value})
```

There is nothing preventing you from calling sess.run() more than once.

Answer (score 0):

@jasekp answer helped me a lot. I have faced the *tensor->ndarray* conversion in the specific case of tensors representing (adversarial) images.

I think that my question/answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443777/how-to-convert-tensor-to-ndarray-tensor-with-adversarial-images-inside/52445055#52445055)) may be an helpful example for the specific case or may help newbies to better understand @jasekp answer.

My example also covers the `matplotlib` image visualization part, but this is OT.

Answer (score -3):

.numpy() will convert tensor to an array.

Comment: its should be a comment instead of answering, because the user has already accepted the answer

Comment: .numpy() works only for eager tensor not normal tensor.